# Can we define a "randomly distributed" unit vector?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

For unit vector $\vec{x}$'s in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is there always an appropriate way to define a randomly distributed unit vector?

I think in $2$-dimensional space, the definition would be pretty simple:
$$
\vec{x} = (\sin\theta,\cos\theta),\; \theta \in U[0,2\pi],
$$
which means $\theta$ has a uniform distribution.

But in $3$-dimensional case or for even larger space, my intuition tells me there is not an appropriate definition, it that true?

Comment: There will always be an appropriate way.  However, we do run into trouble if we keep using angles, as you indicate (at least, the result is non-uniform on the $n-1$-sphere).

Comment: The definition does not transpose as easily, but you can indeed define a "randomly distributed" unit vector. It's exactly equivalent to define a random point on a [hypersphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersphere). See also [Sphere Point Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html) and [Hypersphere Point Picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperspherePointPicking.html) on MathWorld.

Comment: The obvious extension of your definition to 3-space would be $x=(\sin{\theta} \cos{\phi}, \sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}, \cos{\theta})$. This is how you can parametrize the unit sphere. And as @Jean-ClaudeArbaut has already mentioned, you can certainly find a parametrization of the $n-1$ sphere for any dimension $n$. Although the definition itself might not be pretty...

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Actually it *is* pretty, see the links I addded ;-)

Comment: Very cool. And I guess that means that both my and OP's expectation is wrong. Your sphere link says that our choices would end up having points bunched near the poles, and it does make sense. Gotta love the beauty of math.

Answer (score 4):

E.g. let $\vec{Y}$ be a random vector with normal distribution on $\mathbb R^n$ with $\mathbb E\vec{Y}=\vec{0}$  and the identity matrix as covariance matrix.

Then $\vec{X}:=\vec{Y}/||\vec{Y}||$ is a uniformly distributed unit-vector.